# Questions Regarding the concept of factory functions

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if this is possible at all, how ever given [this article](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/factory-functions-pattern-in-depth-356d14801c91#.khkmkfr3w) I am curious as to how a function such as:

```
export default () => {
    let _foo = '';

    return {
      set foo(x) {
          if (x === undefined) {
              _foo = this.someFN();
          } else {
            _foo = x;
          }
      },

      get foo() {
          return _foo;
      },

      someFN() {
        return 'hello'
      }
    }
}
```

There is a concept of, in the article, that there is no "reference to this" in factory functions. If this is the case how do you chain multiple factory functions together?

For instance I am working on a concept where I have written a factory function that has methods which allow you to Chain, an example would be:

```
const fooBar = FooBar();

fooBar.someMethod().someOtherMethod();
```

This works because I return `this`. **Are you to avoid "this" in factory functions?** and **Are factory functions meant to only have one method in them?

So in the case of my example above, would it be wrong to have `someFN()` there?

Comment: This was an example not a working piece of code that has an issue with it, none the less its been fixed. Can you please answer the question in a way I can vote or accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule that you can't use `this` in factory functions. But if you wanted to avoid it, just remember your object in a variable and use that instead (which also avoids issues with the function being called with the wrong `this`):

```
export default () => {
    let _foo = '';
    let obj = {
      set foo(x) {
          if (x === undefined) {
              _foo = this.someFN();
          } else {
            _foo = x;
          }
      },

      get foo() {
          return _foo;
      },

      someFN() {
        return 'hello'
      },

      chainableMethod1() {
          // Do something, then
          return obj;
      },

      chainableMethod2() {
          // Do something else, then
          return obj;
      }
    };

    return obj;
};
```

Usage:

```
theModule.chainableMethod1().chainableMethod2();
```